# 1004 error when trying to run a macro that applies to a table

Tags: vba, excel

I have an existing table.  I want to add a new column next to it, with a formula in it so that the formula adds a new column and fills in all the values.

This is a two-page worksheet.  Table1 is on another page than the table we're working with, but has the master data it draws from.

I recorded a macro of the formula I used to produce this, but when I try to run it, I get

> Run time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

The code I'm using is below:

```
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(INDEX(Table1,MATCH([@Listing],Table1[Property],0)," & _
    "MATCH(""Status"",Table1[#Headers],0))=""for sale"",""seller""," & _
    "IF(INDEX(Table1,MATCH([@Listing],Table1[Property],0)," & _ 
    "MATCH(""Status"",Table1[#Headers],0))=""for lease"",""landlord""," & _
    "IF(INDEX(Table1,MATCH([@Listing],Table1[Property],0)," & _
    "MATCH(""Status"",Table1[#Headers],0))=""for sale or lease"",""seller / landlord""" & _
    "X(Table1,MATCH([@Listing],Table1[Property],0)," & _
    "MATCH(""Base Rent/Mo"",Table1[#Headers],0))>0,""landlord"",""seller""))))"
Range("B1").Select
```

Things I've checked so far:

- All the names match (i.e. Table1 is a valid name, and all the headers are correctly named)
- The formula works exacly as I want to if I just type it in and hit 'enter'
- I've looked for similar issues here, and the most similar seem to be some problems with Pivot tables, but the solutions don't seem to be applicable to my problem

(The reason I'm using VBA for this is that this is one part of a multi-step process that I'm trying to automate to make it simpler to run a complicated report from a large set of data.)

**EDIT**: Additional fixes I tried:

- Moving the master data table to the same sheet as my 'target' table to see if it would work if the two were on the same worksheet. No go.

Comment: have you tried with Formula instead of R1C1? `Range("B2").Formula = ...`

Comment: Same problem.  In addition, I thought that maybe it was that I'd already turned the data on this page into a table, so I tried doing it as a range and adjusting the formula, but I get the same problem.

Comment: Is it a typo here, or are you also missing `Inde` in this part: `"X(Table1,MATCH([@Listing],Table1[Property],0)," & _` ? (the 7th line of your formula)  ...therefore making it `Index(Table1,Match(...`?

Comment: Typo, but still doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two separate issues.

First, I was recording the macro and apparently, Excel will not record formulas longer than a certain length properly. This limit is greater than 407 (the longest formula I got to auto capture), but shorter than 467 characters.  A similar problem was discussed [on this Mr. Excel post](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/585353-visual-basic-applications-formular1c1-size-limitation.html).  This also was why part of the "INDEX" was missing, as BruceWayne pointed out.

In addition, it was necessary to switch from `.FormulaR1C1` to `.Formula` to get it to work correctly, as R3uK had suggested.

The final code ended up as follows:

```
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = _
        "=IF(INDEX(Table1,MATCH($A2,Table1[Property],0),MATCH(""Status"",Table1[#Headers],0))=""for sale"",""seller"",IF(INDEX(Table1,MATCH($A2,Table1[Property],0),MATCH(""Status"",Table1[#Headers],0))=""for lease"",""landlord"",IF(INDEX(Table1,MATCH($A2,Table1[Property],0),MATCH(""Status"",Table1[#Headers],0))=""for sale or lease"",""seller / landlord"",IF(INDEX(Table1,MATCH($A2,Table1[Property],0),MATCH(""Base Rent/Mo"",Table1[#Headers],0))>0,""landlord"",""seller""))))"
Range("B3").Select
```

Answer (score 1):

When you need to use quotes inside quotes like in `"MATCH(""Status"",` which I suppose you are trying to output `Match("Status"` try using `"MATCH("&Chr(34)&Status&Chr(34)`

`Chr(34)` outputs the `"` symbol. Otherwise it would return `MATCH(Status` (without quotes)

Comment: Nope, now I get a syntax error.  (Code is too long to fit in this box's limits.)